# How do I restore administrator account of jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have recently migrated our Jenkins service from Ubuntu to CentOS 7.
The way I did this is by installing a clean instance of Jenkins (2.89) on CentOS 7 and then move the complete contents of JENKINS_HOME from Ubuntu to CentOS 7.

Obviously, when I try to log in as the administrator it fails on the new instance, since I am having the old instance back instead.
Which means I am dealing with the administrator account of old instance.

I tried to find the administrator account of the old instance in one of the /var/lib/jenkins/users//config.xml files. 
But I can't find the definition for the administrator account the config files.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved this all correctly, there should be no problem with the adminstrator ID. My guess is that you have not set JENKINS_HOME on the new machine before starting Jenkins.

Comment: /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8080 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20

This looks good as far as I can judge.

Comment: I have never tried setting JENKINS_HOME has a property. I'm not sure that works. Try just exporting it as an environment variable on the command line  before you run your Jenkins command.